# How to drop a row with the latest date plus multiple other conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
+-----+------------+----------+
| id_ |    date    | existing |
+-----+------------+----------+
|   1 | 01/01/2020 | Y        |
|   2 | 02/01/2020 | Y        |
|   3 | 02/01/2020 | N        |
|   4 | 03/01/2020 | Y        |
|   5 | 03/01/2020 | N        |
|   6 | 03/01/2020 | N        |
|   7 | 04/01/2020 | Y        |
+-----+------------+----------+
```

I want to drop the row with the latest `date` that is not marked as `existing`. If there are multiple qualifying rows then the row with the lowest `id_` should be dropped. The expected output would be:

```
+-----+------------+----------+
| id_ |    date    | existing |
+-----+------------+----------+
|   1 | 01/01/2020 | Y        |
|   2 | 02/01/2020 | Y        |
|   3 | 02/01/2020 | N        |
|   4 | 03/01/2020 | Y        |
|   6 | 03/01/2020 | N        |
|   7 | 04/01/2020 | Y        |
+-----+------------+----------+
```

I know how to drop the latest `date` or `id_` by sorting and then using `head()` and I know how to drop non-existing rows using `drop()` with a condition. However, how would I apply all the conditions at the same time so that they only delete the one applicable row as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you better sort:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['date'], ascending = True)
```

Then you need to delete the last row:

```
df = df.drop(df[df['existing']=='N'].tail(1).index)
```

Comment: Thanks for giving this a go. Sadly I get an error from the second line: ```Exception has occurred: KeyError False```

Comment: Figured out the problem. Final row should be ```df =df.drop(df[df['existing']=='N'].tail(1).index)```

Comment: This also needs two sort conditions as follows: ```df = df.sort_values(by=['date', "id_"], ascending=[True, False])```

Comment: will do though you'll need to correct it first as per my comments! Or I can do it?